# how to align popup to the left of the view

Tags: android, popup, alignment

I need to display a popup window whenever user presses the imageView(the present image).
This popup window must be aligned to the left of the imageView as shown in the attached image.
[image]

How It can be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this line code:

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(image,Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: This shows the `popupWindow` in the top left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

To align the PopupWindow to the left of the trigger view, you must know the width of the PopupWinow before it is drawn.

```
// Before popup , need to get PopupWindow size.
// because contentView is not drawn in this time, width/height is 0.
// so, need to by measure to get contentView's size.
private static int makeDropDownMeasureSpec(int measureSpec) {
        int mode;
        if (measureSpec == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            mode = View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
        } else {
            mode = View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        }
        return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec), mode);
}
```

then

```
// measure contentView size
View contentView = popupWindow.getContentView();
// need to measure first, because in this time PopupWindow is nit pop, width is 0.
contentView.measure(makeDropDownMeasureSpec(popupWindow.getWidth()),
                makeDropDownMeasureSpec(popupWindow.getHeight()));

int offsetX = -popupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredWidth();
int offsetY = -mTriggerView.getHeight();
// show at the left edge of the trigger view
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mTriggerView, offsetX, offsetY);
```